# Why does run is not working on my Android studio?

Tags: android-studio

I tried to run Android studio but it is not working whereas preview is working correctly.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please check How to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Your question isn't very detailed and nobody can help you with this short text.